# Java Stream API: how to convert to a Map of Sets

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, java-stream

Lets say I have  following an class named `Employee` and a List of these `Employee`-classes:

```
class Employee {

private String praefix;
private String middleFix;
private String postfix;
private String name;

public Employee(String praefix, String middleFix, String postfix, String name) {
    this.praefix = praefix;
    this.middleFix = middleFix;
    this.postfix = postfix;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPraefix() {
    return praefix;
}

public void setPraefix(String praefix) {
    this.praefix = praefix;
}

public String getMiddleFix() {
    return middleFix;
}

public void setMiddleFix(String middleFix) {
    this.middleFix = middleFix;
}

public String getPostfix() {
    return postfix;
}

public void setPostfix(String postfix) {
    this.postfix = postfix;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
employees.add(new Employee("A", "B", "C", "Michael Phelps"));
employees.add(new Employee("A", "B", "C", "Cristiano Ronaldo"));
employees.add(new Employee("D", "E", "F", "Usain Bolton"));
employees.add(new Employee("D", "E", "F", "Diego Armando Maradona"));
employees.add(new Employee("D", "E", "F", "Lionel Messi"));
```

Is it possible to convert it to following Map with Java Stream-API?

```
{A.B.C=[Cristiano Ronaldo, Michael Phelps], D.E.F=[Aydin Korkmaz, Diego Armando Maradona, Usain Bolton]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  Map<String, List<String>> result = employees.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    x -> String.join(".",
                            x.getPraefix(),
                            x.getMiddleFix(),
                            x.getPostfix()),
                    Collectors.mapping(Employee::getName, Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: `Stream.of(x.getPraefix(), x.getMiddleFix(), x.getPostfix())
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(".")` could be replaced with simple concatenation using `+`

Comment: @Ivan ooh my! thx, this is what happens when I try to do two things at a time.

Comment: That leaves out the "." delimiter though. I think the first one was better.

Comment: @Vasan neither :) how about a 3-rd option (that I actually would use myself)

Comment: Ah yes, I'd forgot about StringJoiner. +1

Comment: @Vasan this can be even further simplified with `String.join` btw

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultSet = employees.stream()
             .collect(toMap(e ->
               String.join(".", e.getPraefix(), e.getMiddleFix(), e.getPostfix()),
               v -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(v.getName())),
               (left, right) -> {left.addAll(right); return left;}));
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to have today in default jdk, `ArrayList.of(...)`, or `HashSet.of(...)`, would make this a little nicer

Comment: @Eugene couldn't agree more, it's definitely long-winded with the current approach.